# Rails: using link_to to make a link without href

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I use the `link_to` helper to make a link without an `href` attribute? I want to make a link exclusively for a javascript action, I don't want it reloading the page or anything.

When I omit the url parameter, clicking the link reloads the page. Ditto for providing `nil` in place of the url.

Comment: have you tried setting the url to "#"?

Comment: Doing "#" makes it reload the page. I know I can override the link action with JS, but seems there should be an even simpler solution with `link_to`

Comment: what HTML is it generating for you? At the end of the day, your JS should prevent the default link clicking behavior anyways. This may be a non-issue.

Comment: You might also consider just using a button instead of <a> for semantic reasons.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I use this approach:

```
= link_to('Click me', 'javascript:;', :id => :foo)
```

Its basically a Javascript `no-op`

Comment: This works. Ended up just making an `a`-tag without an href- that way browsers won't show the `javascript:;` link destination preview in the lower-left.

Comment: What's the difference from `javascript:void(0)`?

Answer (score 50):

You can also use a

```
content_tag("a","link text")
```

which gives you

```
<a>link text</a>
```

or, from the comment from @cesartalves, with a block:

```
content_tag("a") do
  image_tag("src") 
end
```

See: [rails api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag)

Comment: Clever, however, it appears that links without an href attribute don't cause the cursor to change to a pointer (it stays as a text cursor).

Comment: Seems like modern versions of Rails use cursor pointer now. :)

Comment: By the way, you can also use this with a block:
`content_tag("a") do
    image_tag("src")
end`

Answer (score 13):

Set the href to:

```
javascript:void(0)
```

This will let you have a link that clicking it does nothing, doesn't reload the page, and doesn't move the page up to the top.

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= link_to '+ Add Make', 'javascript:void(0)', id: 'add-make', onclick: 'addMake()' %>
```

and then your jQuery:

```
function addMake() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/dealers',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'script',
    success: function (data) {
      console.log('it was successful')
      $('.add-make').hide();
    },
    error: function (data) {
      console.log('it was error')
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is

```
= link_to("My hyperlink", "#")
```

This will give you a link that when clicked, does not reload the page like passing in nil. At the same time, it will set the mouse to pointer on mouseover, which you will not get with the content_tag approach.

Comment: This is okay in some places, but it will bounce the screen to the top of your page.  Adding the 'javascript:;' as suggested above probably the better way to go in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're better off using a button in situations where there is no href.

```
<button class='button'>Hello</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

An example for rails 5 would be:

`<%= content_tag("a", image_tag("/logo.png"), class: "navbar-brand") %>`

This would render as:

`<a class="navbar-brand"><img src="/logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>`

This is similar to [niels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1440497/niels)' answer but with a nested `image_tag` and a class.

Source: [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using plain HTML without `href` attribute at all in such cases:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open dialog</a>
```

IMHO it is more readable than `content_tag("a","link text")`.

- The disadvantage of `href=#` is that the browser will scroll to the top
  when clicked by default
- `javascript:;` looks ugly