# Rails automatic link_to javascript:void()

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know that using `:back` with [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) generates an anchor with `javascript:history.back()` as its `href`:

```
link_to :back, "Go Back!"
```

generates

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()">Go Back!</a>
```

is there any comparable symbol (such as `:back`) which would generate something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void();">This does nothing!</a>
```

This can be used in combination with dropdowns.

**BTW: I DON'T want to use something as described in this question:**

[Rails: using link_to to make a link without href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081156/rails-using-link-to-to-make-a-link-without-href)

Comment: You could create your own helper named `link_to_js_void(title, options ={})` which would return `link_to(title, 'javascript:void();', options)`

Comment: I think eventually thats the only way possible.

Comment: If you are going to use the link in a dropdown, you are attaching js-code to the clicking of the link, right?

Comment: @nathanvda not really, bootstrap does it for me. Why?

Comment: So why do you need this then? Any attached javascript will prevent the default behaviour, so you can  create a default link (href='#'), no need for including an explicit javascript action.

Comment: Maybe I don't want to combine it with dropdown, who knows? erasing the question doesn't solve it!