# Rails link_to: click but stay in place, do not jump to top of page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `link_to` in my rails app.  It functions as a tooltip.  When the user hovers over the link: It displays some helper text.

If the user accidentally clicks the tooltip: I do not want the default behavior of jumping to the top of the page.  I know with javascript I could `preventDefault`, but is there an easy rails way to get this same behavior?

I was thinking of `remote: true` but it still jumps to the top of the page.

Code:

```
<%= link_to "#", title: 'my helper text', remote: true do %>
  <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an empty anchor will result in scrolling to the document start, as you've experienced. Specifying a non-existent anchor, however, will result in no change in scroll position. For example:

```
<a href="#doesnotexist">Stay Here</a>
```

This will still change the document URL and the browser history, though, which is a worse user experience.

For links that shouldn't change the page, such as those handled via JS, you should absolutely use progressive enhancement and prevent the browser action in JS with the most appropriate method (e.g., `return false` or `e.preventDefault`).

If you have tooltips that should not actually link anywhere, perhaps it would be best to change them into another inline element, such as `span`.

Comment: I would add that your anchor target *should* exist. You could give the link an ID and use the same ID as the link in the href.

Comment: Having the JavaScript `return false` and `preventDefault()` on the event should stop things from getting that far anyway.

Comment: YES, YES, YES! Don't use a link unless you *need* a link. `span` is a much better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an `<a>` tag along with `onclick="return false;"` As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081156/rails-using-link-to-to-make-a-link-without-href#answer-12086087):

```
<a onclick="return false;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="<%= my_helper_text%>”><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></a>
```

Comment: You should not be using `onclick`. While that was acceptable in 1996, that is considered bad practice in 2016.

Answer (score 0):

In circumstances like this, I've usually been successful in using `nil`.

```
<%= link_to nil, title: 'my helper text' %>
  <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
<% end %>
```

After some research, I'm seen a few people claim that `javascript:;` is what should be used, but I haven't experienced any issues using `nil`.

Comment: Never, ever, ever use `javascript:;` it is invalid.

Comment: Karl,  I don't know anything about `javascript:;` so i don't know why it is so bad.  I just know when i was researching some answers help the question poster, **MANY** of them mentioned using that line of code.

Can you please expound a to why it is a bad idea to use `javascript:;`

Comment: No worries, here you go ... `javascript:` is not a valid protocol (it is a "*psudo*-protocol"), thus is not a valid URL. *Some* browsers may support it, but that doesn't make it valid. Having read the RFCs and the HTML specifications, I can assure you that it is not valid.

Microsoft *does* support it though: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767736(v=vs.85).aspx )

Mozilla supports it but it is discouraged: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void

Comment: Some other SO refs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321469/when-do-i-need-to-specify-the-javascript-protocol and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068781/what-does-the-javascript-pseudo-protocol-actually-do

Answer (score 0):

Unless you *need* an actual link, don't use an anchor element. Use the proper HTML element. This this case, you should use a `span` element.

You should be able to do this:

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="<%= my_helper_text%>”><span class="fa fa-question-circle"></span></span>
```

or maybe even this:

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="my helper text" class="fa fa-question-circle"></span>
```